# ASP.NET Google Maps API not reading long/lat from variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I have a variable accepting the long/lat from the database.
I am passing the variable to the map but the map comes up gray on loading.
My variable has the correct long/lat as it reads the correct data to a textbox, and my map is also functioning correctly as if I hard code in a long/lat it will load correctly.

This is my code:

```
 conn1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT LocLat FROM Specialists where SpName = '" + Convert.ToString(this.PreviousPage.Session["id"]) + "'", conn1);
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            da2.Fill(ds2);
        String SpLoc = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 

        lblIn.Text = SpLoc;

        GLatLng mainLocation = new GLatLng(SpLoc);
        GMap1.setCenter(mainLocation, 15);

        XPinLetter xpinLetter = new XPinLetter(PinShapes.pin_star, "C", Color.Blue, Color.White, Color.Chocolate);
        GMap1.Add(new GMarker(mainLocation, new GMarkerOptions(new GIcon(xpinLetter.ToString(), xpinLetter.Shadow()))));

        conn1.Close();
```

This is how the page appears after running:

[image: This is how the page appears after running]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://maps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_300_Asignar-Centro.aspx`

You are supplying a single value to the constructor whereas you need the below and to convert to Double:

```
String lat = SpLoc.Split(',')[0];
String lng = SpLoc.Split(',')[1]:

Double lat1 = Convert.ToDouble(lat);
Double lng1 = Convert.ToDouble(lng);

GLatLng mainLocation = new GLatLng(lat1, lng1);
```

You will need to extract the latitude and longitude from your database return or in your database return.

This also appears to be subgurim-maps you may want to add that to the tag. I don't have this package installed to test.